# Block user changes to Windows 10 system variables

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, group-policy

We are using a virtual desktop solution that runs Windows 10 in an un-locked-down state. For reasons, the desktops are not joined to a domain so only a local GPO can be applied.

We want non-admin users to be able to set their own environment variables, but I've found that non-admin accounts can also change the system environment variables. We have provided guidance on setting user variables and advised against changing system variables but I don't want to rely on the honor system.

I've looked through the local group policies but didn't identify anything that would prevent non-admin users from modifying system variables. Does a policy exist for this?

Comment: Users can overwrite system environment variables so effectively a system env variable is replaced by a user env variable. But that does not mean that users can change the system variable. Best example is PATH which exists as system variable and can be replaced or extended by a user specified variable.

Comment: If you do not want rely on the honor system then you will have to lock down the machine

Comment: @Ramhound That's what asking about: How to lock it down so users can't edit the system environment variables.

Comment: @Robert This is correct, users _can_ overwrite the system variables with their own user variables. My concern is that while testing this as a regular user, I was able to edit the system variable and save it. Not a terrible problem since the desktop instance is spun up from a gold image and any changes are erased as soon as the session is closed, but it still poses a risk.

Comment: How did you change the environment variables (which command)? Do you use Windows AppLocker to restrict program execution?

Comment: @Robert I used System Properties in Control Panel. I'm not familiar with AppLocker. I'll look into that since we have other things to restrict as well.